# What is the profile picture of the double split interferences: from "far", up to the wall with holes through this one, and until we reach the emitter

Tags: double-slit-experiment

I would like to know what are "scientitifics" therms to explain better what I mean.
I mean we do a cross section, normal to the trajectory of photons and we make it changing position all the way long while the emission occurs. What would look like the observation of interferences along the trajectory ?

A screen right at the end of the splits will determine the position of a photon, but up to a certain point we oberve intereferences ?

Good day.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You want to see the near-field of a double slit experiment? https://opg.optica.org/josaa/abstract.cfm?uri=josaa-30-11-2273 I would also advise you to forget about the idea of the "position of a photon". No such thing exists. Photons are not objects. They are irreversible energy exchanges.